# SQL Insert Statement that pulls top n from each set of categories that could have duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to write an Insert statement that will go through sales numbers for a group of people with each sale being marked as an R or C type of sale. I want to find the TOP 100 salespersons in ALL (both R and C), R, and C. Not only do I have sales data though, I have Sales, Margin, Count, Sales/Count data I want to do the same thing for. so far I have to do **12 SQL statements** to accomplish this (4 categories X 3 sales types) each one is a slight variation of this to get one of my 4 categories.

```
INSERT INTO ztbl_AllTopSalesPerson (SalesPerson)
SELECT TOP 100 tbl_Master.SalesPerson
FROM tbl_Master
WHERE tbl_Master.SaleType="C"
GROUP BY tbl_Master.SalesPerson
ORDER BY Sum(tbl_Master.Margin) DESC;

INSERT INTO ztbl_AllTopSalesPerson (SalesPerson)
SELECT TOP 100 tbl_Master.SalesPerson
FROM tbl_Master
WHERE tbl_Master.SaleType="R"
GROUP BY tbl_Master.SalesPerson
ORDER BY Sum(tbl_Master.Margin) DESC;

INSERT INTO ztbl_AllTopSalesPerson (SalesPerson)
SELECT TOP 100 tbl_Master.SalesPerson
FROM tbl_Master
GROUP BY tbl_Master.SalesPerson
ORDER BY Sum(tbl_Master.Margin) DESC;
```

Ideally I would like a way to make this all **one statement**. And(if it is not impossible) I would like to filter each one by date so I can do it by monthly data too, not just overall.

Just a few notes: I cant have duplicate names, so if a salesperson is top in all three sales types, they still only appear once. Im using Access with a SQL Server back-end for only the main data table. I cant take the top 300 results, because there is so much overlap between the sales types, and I need the top from each ( I do a separate query after this list is made that lines up the SalesPersons' Alphabetically with their 4 categories as fields). And lastly, I generally up with a final list that has around 260-290 records.
THANKS!
p.s. thanks for your replies, stack exchange has saved my bacon 100s of times. I would post my attempts at this, but I think it would hurt more than it would help.

Comment: If this is SQL Server and not MS Access, look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) to get you started with partitioning and aggregate functions.

Comment: To me your requirement reads as: "I need to rank each salesperson in n categories and want anyone returned who's rank is <= 100 in *one or more* of the categories". Is that correct?

Comment: yes that seems about right. but the categories are sums within a specific date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to tweak it a little depending on what sort of output you want. You also might have to do a subquery for the COUNT(*) part of it, as this is untested. But I think this is the general idea of what you are looking for.

To get aggregated information, you can break it up into two CTE's:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT SalesPerson,
    SaleType,
    SUM(Margin) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesPerson,SaleType) as Margin,
    SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesPerson,SaleType) as Sales,
    SUM(Sales)/COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesPerson,SaleType) as Sales_pct,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesPerson,SaleType) as Total
    SUM(Margin) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesPerson) as Margin_all,
    SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesPerson) as Sales_all,
    SUM(Sales)/COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesPerson) as Sales_pct_all,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesPerson) as Total_all
    FROM tbl_Master
    )

,CTE2 AS (
    SELECT SalesPerson
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SaleType ORDER BY Margin desc) as Margin
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SaleType ORDER BY Sales desc) as Sales
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SaleType ORDER BY Sales_pct desc) as Sales_pct
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Master.SaleType ORDER BY Total desc) as Total
    ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Margin_all desc) as Margin_all
    ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Sales_all desc) as Sales_all
    ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Sales_pct_all desc) as Sales_pct_all
    ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Total_all desc) as Total_all
    FROM CTE1         )

Select distinct SalesPerson from CTE2
    Where Margin <= 100 Or Sales <= 100 Or Total <= 100 or Sales_pct <= 100
    Or Margin_all <= 100 Or Sales_all <= 100 Or Total_all <= 100 or Sales_pct_all <= 100
```

I understand this is not perfect, but it should get you started. To filter by date, add `DATEPART(month,[your date field])` to your `PARTITION BY` clauses (and the first CTE)

Comment: I dont see and sum , or group by clauses. Do I not need them? I'm working right now actually on it with the advice I have been given

Comment: This works wonders now. Im guessing that the Transact SQL is loads more powerful than Access SQL. I just did a pass-through query and edited that SQL and its working great. Im just getting hung up on the DATEPART but that might be because Im still a greenhorn at T-SQL

Comment: @ALPHAB3TS00P You actually might not be able to use DATEPART within a PARTITION BY clause. In that case you can add a column `DATEPART(month,[datefield]) as Month` ([datefield] being whatever the name of the column you use to store date) to CTE1, and then edit CTE2 so it has `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SaleType,Month ORDER BY ...`

Comment: There is still an issue with the "all" parts `,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Margin desc) as Margin_all` because CTE1 is grouping by SaleType it is not actually pulling the top 100 from (type1 + type2)